# Different results in differentiation; I don't see the flaw

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Might be getting sleepy here, but I cannot find an issue in both methods which yields different results.

> The function in concern is $f(\theta)=nk \text{log}\theta - (k+1)\sum^n \text{log}(\theta+\frac{y_i}{k})$ where $k>0$ is a known constant and $\theta$ is an unknown variable. The $y_i$ is a series of $n$ observations(so $n$ is known integer)...just take them as a series of numbers which are known. Basiaclly, each $y_i$ can be treated as constants here. I want to find $\frac{d^2f}{d \theta ^2}$.

Step 1, I need to find $\frac{df}{d \theta}$ which I reason as follows

> $\frac{df}{d \theta}=nk \frac{d}{d\theta}\text{log}\theta-(k+1)\sum \frac{d}{d \theta} \text{log}(\theta+\frac{y_i}{k})=\frac{nk}{\theta}-(k+1)\sum\frac{1}{\theta+\frac{y_i}{k}}$.

Now, here's where it gets weird; case 1. I leave $\frac{1}{\theta+\frac{y_i}{k}}$ as it is in the sum. case 2. I simplify it to $\frac{1}{\theta+\frac{y_i}{k}}=\frac{k \theta + y_i}{k}$ and proceed with the second differentiation. It shouldn't, but it does, yield different results...

> case 1. $\frac{d^2f}{d \theta^2}=-\frac{nk}{\theta^2}-(k+1)\sum\frac{d}{d\theta}\frac{1}{\theta+\frac{y_i}{k}}=-\frac{nk}{\theta^2}-(k+1)\sum\frac{d}{d\theta}(\theta+\frac{y_i}{k})^{-1}$
>
> $=-\frac{nk}{\theta^2}-(k+1)\sum(-1)(\theta+\frac{y_i}{k})^{-2}(1)$
>
> $=-\frac{nk}{\theta^2}+(k+1)\sum(\theta+\frac{y_i}{k})^{-2}$

Now,

> case 2. $\frac{d^2f}{d \theta^2}=-\frac{nk}{\theta^2}-(k+1)\sum\frac{d}{d\theta}\frac{k\theta+y_i}{k}=\frac{d^2f}{d \theta^2}=-\frac{nk}{\theta^2}-\frac{(k+1)}{k}\sum\frac{d}{d\theta}(k\theta+y_i)$
>
> $=-\frac{nk}{\theta^2}-\frac{(k+1)}{k}\sum k$
>
> $=-\frac{nk}{\theta^2}-\frac{(k+1)}{k}nk$
>
> $=-\frac{nk}{\theta^2}-(k+1)n$

where did I make my mistake? in which one? please point them out explicitly, very frustrated with myself right now!

Comment: I think you simplified the fraction incorrectly at the start of case 2; it should be inverted.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\theta+\frac{y_i}{k}}=\frac{k}{k \theta + y_i}$

Comment: You guys are absolutely right, thanks for pointing it out, it works fine now. Not the best time of the day to do maths, appreciate it lads